# How can I get the noun phrase without space as input sentence after parsing with parseLine in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, parsing, token, opennlp

I am using `Parse[] parses = parseLine(sentence, parser, tokenizer, numParses)` in OpenNLP to get noun phrases of the sentence. `parseLine` preprocess the sentences to tokenize brackets and parantheses by appending with a space.

Let’s say input sentence containing paranthesis as below:

```
sentence= "This is an example sentence (example).";
```

After parsing, `an example sentence (example)` becomes `an example sentence ( example )`.

How can I get the original noun phrase instead of one by appending with a space after parsing by using its `Parse` object?